# Cropping rectangular photos from scans in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a bunch of photos like this:

[image: Asakusa photo scan]

I would like to automatically crop the image so that just the photograph (and possibly the caption) are shown.

I tried detecting contours, but they found the borders of objects in the photo and not the photo itself. There's also a spurious contour for the edges of the image as well as other small ones.

[image: Bad contours]

What can I do to get just the rectangle that includes the photo?

Comment: check this https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/

Comment: Thanks, but the method there won't work. It relies on photos of the paper having good contours for the paper edges, which isn't the case with the photo in my image (notice there's no contour for the upper edge).

Comment: Well, to invite answers to that you shall edit your question title mentioning images with bad contour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to come up with a satisfactory solution to this. There are a few steps:

1. Get contours
2. Remove contours that are too small or too large in area
3. Find the min/max x/y over all remaining contours
4. Use those values to create a rectangle to crop in

That's the basic process.

Anyway, here's some code for the core parts:

```
import cv2
from os.path import basename
from glob import glob

def get_contours(img):
    # First make the image 1-bit and get contours
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 150, 255, 0)

    cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg', thresh)
    img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

    # filter contours that are too large or small
    size = get_size(img)
    contours = [cc for cc in contours if contourOK(cc, size)]
    return contours

def get_size(img):
    ih, iw = img.shape[:2]
    return iw * ih

def contourOK(cc, size=1000000):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cc)
    if w < 50 or h < 50: return False # too narrow or wide is bad
    area = cv2.contourArea(cc)
    return area < (size * 0.5) and area > 200

def find_boundaries(img, contours):
    # margin is the minimum distance from the edges of the image, as a fraction
    ih, iw = img.shape[:2]
    minx = iw
    miny = ih
    maxx = 0
    maxy = 0

    for cc in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cc)
        if x < minx: minx = x
        if y < miny: miny = y
        if x + w > maxx: maxx = x + w
        if y + h > maxy: maxy = y + h

    return (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

def crop(img, boundaries):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = boundaries
    return img[miny:maxy, minx:maxx]

def process_image(fname):
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    contours = get_contours(img)
    #cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0)) # draws contours, good for debugging
    bounds = find_boundaries(img, contours)
    cropped = crop(img, bounds)
    if get_size(cropped) < 400: return # too small
    cv2.imwrite('cropped/' + basename(fname), cropped)

process_image('pic.jpg')
```

This has the important parts, but I used two other tricks that worked well for my data set:

1. Modify the threshold until a certain percentage of the image is black. For most of my images even the lightest part of a photo is darker than the page underneath, so at a certain magic threshold level the photo becomes a black square and thus easier to get good contours for.
2. Completely ignore contours near the edges of the image. Sometimes a bit of the spine of the book causes contours to form at the borders of the original image, which is undesirable. Checking for contours within a small pixel count (like 20) of the edge and ignoring them solved that problem.

Some result images, original on left and autocropped on right:

[image: Street with streetcar]

[image: People in a park]

Comment: Ended up releasing my code for this here: https://github.com/polm/ndl-crop

Comment: Just use adaptivethreshold. It will work in most cases unlike the threshold which will only work if image has similar brightness.